# In feed - programmatically add magento product

Tags: magento, import, product

I have a import script that reads XML data and imports products in Magento and I've managed to make it work like a charm, except one thing. When product is imported I'd like to set option "In Feed" to "Yes".

I tried to get class methods with get_class_methods() but I didn't find anything similar. I've then inspected the element in the back-end (if you are editing product) and found that label "In Feed" is for a field "is_imported".

I've searched google, but found nothing. Has anyone ever had a similar problem and found a solution? My Magento version is 1.5 (but it would be great if it would work on 1.6 too).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set field "in feed" to yes, you must set is_imported property to 1 when importing products. You can do that with this piece of code:

```
     $product->setIsImported(1);
```

tested it on Magento version 1.6

Comment: Has anyone noticed that the is_imported attribute is missing in a clean 1.7.0.2 install?